# XSLT-Transformation with Saxon9he throws java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index

Tags: java, xml, xslt, saxon

I'm trying an xsl transformation with saxon and I'm having trouble with the file names:

```
package com.fop;

import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

public class XMLtoFO {

    private static StreamResult out;
    private static StreamSource xml;
    private static StreamSource xsl;
    private static Transformer transformer;

    // TODO

    protected static void xmlToFO(String inputXSL, String[] inputxml,
            String[] fofilname) throws Exception {
        if (true) {
            System.setProperty("javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory",
                    "net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl");
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < inputxml.length; i++) {
            try {
                      out = new StreamResult( fofilname[i]  );
                      xml = new StreamSource( inputxml[i] );
                      xsl = new StreamSource( inputXSL );
                      transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer( xsl );
                      transformer.transform( xml, out );
                System.err.println("\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

Error on line 12 of root-template.xsl:
  java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 19: 3-Leiter-Steuerung,Methode 2_result.fo.xml
; SystemID: file:/C:/Users/z003a5bp/Desktop/root-template.xsl; Line#: 12; Column#: -1
net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 19: 3-Leiter-Steuerung, Methode 2_result.fo.xml
    at net.sf.saxon.serialize.Emitter.makeOutputStream(Emitter.java:200)
    at net.sf.saxon.serialize.Emitter.makeWriter(Emitter.java:160)
    at net.sf.saxon.serialize.XMLEmitter.openDocument(XMLEmitter.java:145)
    at net.sf.saxon.serialize.XMLEmitter.startElement(XMLEmitter.java:309)
    at net.sf.saxon.event.NamespaceReducer.startElement(NamespaceReducer.java:73)
    at net.sf.saxon.event.ComplexContentOutputter.startContent(ComplexContentOutputter.java:558)
    at net.sf.saxon.event.ComplexContentOutputter.startElement(ComplexContentOutputter.java:183)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.ElementCreator.processLeavingTail(ElementCreator.java:424)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.ElementCreator.processLeavingTail(ElementCreator.java:373)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.Block.processLeavingTail(Block.java:660)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.Instruction.process(Instruction.java:138)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.ElementCreator.processLeavingTail(ElementCreator.java:431)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.ElementCreator.processLeavingTail(ElementCreator.java:373)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.Template.applyLeavingTail(Template.java:239)
    at net.sf.saxon.trans.Mode.applyTemplates(Mode.java:1057)
    at net.sf.saxon.Controller.transformDocument(Controller.java:2080)
    at net.sf.saxon.Controller.transform(Controller.java:1903)
    at com.fop.XMLtoFO.xmlToFO(XMLtoFO.java:29)
    at com.fop.Layout.output(Layout.java:151)
    at com.fop.Layout.actionPerformed(Layout.java:168)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 19: 3-Leiter-Steuerung, Methode 2_result.fo.xml
    at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URI.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at net.sf.saxon.serialize.Emitter.makeOutputStream(Emitter.java:172)
    ... 55 more
```

The problem is that many filenames have spaces or commas or things like that. What would be the best way to handle that? Have all input files pass through a character-escaping method?

I was looking at this and guess my problem is something similar:
http://sourceforge.net/p/saxon/discussion/94027/thread/b43bb749/

But that discussion is a little over my head.

UPDATE: I changed the constructors accordingly. Now I get this:

```
Error 
  I/O error reported by XML parser processing
  file:/C:/Users/z003a5bp/Desktop/Workspace/FOP/file:C:/Users/z003a5bp/Desktop/3-Leiter-Steuerung,%20Methode%202.xml: C:\Users\z003a5bp\Desktop\Workspace\FOP\file:C:\Users\z003a5bp\Desktop\3-Leiter-Steuerung, Methode 2.xml (the filename, directory name or volume label syntax is incorrect)
net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: I/O error reported by XML parser processing file:/C:/Users/z003a5bp/Desktop/Workspace/FOP/file:C:/Users/z003a5bp/Desktop/3-Leiter-Steuerung,%20Methode%202.xml: C:\Users\z003a5bp\Desktop\Workspace\FOP\file:C:\Users\z003a5bp\Desktop\3-Leiter-Steuerung, Methode 2.xml (the filename, directory name or volume label syntax is incorrect)
    at net.sf.saxon.event.Sender.sendSAXSource(Sender.java:427)
    at net.sf.saxon.event.Sender.send(Sender.java:169)
    at net.sf.saxon.Controller.transform(Controller.java:1890)
    at com.fop.XMLtoFO.xmlToFO(XMLtoFO.java:29)
    at com.fop.Layout.output(Layout.java:151)
    at com.fop.Layout.actionPerformed(Layout.java:168)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\z003a5bp\Desktop\Workspace\FOP\file:C:\Users\z003a5bp\Desktop\3-Leiter-Steuerung, Methode 2.xml (the filename, directory name or volume label syntax is incorrect)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at net.sf.saxon.event.Sender.sendSAXSource(Sender.java:396)
    ... 41 more
```

This is how I read the files:

```
protected static void openXMLChooser() {
    setUIManager();

    FileFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("XML files", "xml");
    chooser = new JFileChooser();
    chooser.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);
    chooser.addChoosableFileFilter(filter);
    chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
    if (chooser.getSelectedFile() != null
            && chooser.getSelectedFiles() != null)
        infoarea.append("No file(s)\n");
}
```

And this is how I change the filename:

```
protected String[] fileName(String exten) {
    file = chooser.getSelectedFiles();
    pdffilename = new String[file .length];
    for (int i = 0; i < file .length; i++) {
        pdffilename[i] = file [i].getName();
        b = new StringBuilder(pdffilename[i]);
        b.replace(pdffilename[i].lastIndexOf("."),
                pdffilename[i].lastIndexOf("l") + 1, "_result"+exten+"");
        pdffilename[i] = b.toString();
    }
    return pdffilename;
}
```

And here I call the function:

```
XMLtoFO.xmlToFO(inputxsl, inputxml, this.fileName("fo.xml"));
```

Answer (score 2):

Filenames are not URIs; you are using a filename where a URI is expected.

The simplest answer is to use the constructors for StreamSource that expect a File rather than a URI. So change

```
new StreamSource(X)
```

to

```
new StreamSource(new File(X))
```

because the "new File()" constructor works with file names. (Internally, the file name will be automatically converted to a URI, but you don't need to worry about that).